# Adding deleted Gmail account back to iPad

Tags: gmail, mobile-mail

I accidentally deleted one of my Gmail accounts from my iPad.  It is still on my iPhone and my computer, but I can't add it to my list of email accounts because it still exists as my account.

Does anyone know how to make it show up again on my iPad?  Such a silly mistake!
Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "it still exists as my account"?

Comment: I can still access the account on all my devices, but it is not listed as an account under settings-mail-accounts

Comment: Do you use the Mail app on your iPad, or the Gmail app?

Comment: I use the mail app on my ipad

Comment: So you can still access your Gmail account in Mail, even though it's not showing up in Settings?

Comment: I can access my email, but in the list of my email accounts it is not showing up.